# How to format DateFormatter(NSDateFormattter) for Date String

Tags: objective-c, swift

How to construct formatter(NSFormatter) for following Date string

```
Date dateString = "Sun Oct 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss" // This line is not working
let dd: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print("Date \(dd)") // Is returning null
```

API Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter

Comment: You are not taking in account in your `dateFormat` that part of your date string: `GMT+0530 (IST)`. So it's normal that `dd` is nil.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Dateformatter, can you please tell me how to represent GMT +0530 (IST)

Comment: Look there for `GMT +0530`: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I don't see any references for  (IST) in link you have mentioned. How can I ignore "GMT+0530 (IST)"

Comment: "E MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" works for "Sun Oct 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT", I couldn't crack "+0530 (IST)" at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to tell `DateFormatter` to ignore the 'GMT' part, because that throws it off. GMT is implied if you have `+0530` though, so you don't need it.

For this string:

```
let dateString = "Sun Oct 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530"
```

This format works:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'x"
```

If the `(IST)` is always the same, you can tell the date formatter to ignore it too by using

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'x '(IST)'"
```

If that part can vary, you should probably use String methods to remove that part of the string before parsing the date.